# Triggering an event when clicking on a DataLabel object

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to trigger an event in an Excel Macro when I click on a DataLabel object in an ActiveChart. I can't use a SheetChange event because the change is happening in a chart. It's probably simple, but I'm just having a hard time getting the correct syntax to trigger this kind of event. Thanks!

Comment: Try selecting the data label you're trying to mark, then running this in the VBA editor: `Debug.Print Selection.Name`. Does anything come up? Also try `Debug.Print Selection.Type`. Perhaps there's some workaround you can use in the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event.

Comment: The `DataLabel` class exposes no events. So.. tough luck! Use the Object Browser (F2) to locate the `Chart` class and see if there wouldn't be a useful event to handle, then look into how `WithEvents` works.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty tricky! It's much easier if the chart is on a separate Chart Sheet but I've never actually used one of those. Jon Peltier has a longer walkthrough [here](https://peltiertech.com/chart-events-microsoft-excel/) but this is the gist of it:

1. Create a new class module called "ChartClass". Put this in it:

   ```
   Public WithEvents chartThing As Chart
   Private Sub chartThing_Select(ByVal ElementID As Long, ByVal Arg1 As Long, ByVal Arg2 As Long)

       Dim paramType As String
       paramType = TypeName(Selection)

       If paramType = "DataLabel" Or paramType = "DataLabels" Then
           'Do whatever you want
           MsgBox "You've selected some labels"
       End If

   End Sub
   ```
2. Put this in a standard module:

   ```
   Dim chartThings() As New ChartClass
   Sub setCharts()

       Dim ws As Worksheet
       Dim chartCount As Long
       Set ws = ActiveSheet
       chartCount = ws.ChartObjects.Count

       If chartCount > 0 Then
           ReDim chartThings(1 To chartCount)
           Dim i As Long
           For i = 1 To chartCount
               Set chartThings(i).chartThing = ws.ChartObjects(i).Chart
           Next
       End If

   End Sub
   ```
3. Add this Worksheet_Activate event to the sheet containing the chart:

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

       Call setCharts

   End Sub
   ```